# Adicionar evento de click a uma DataTable do Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Eu estou tentando ativar uma função com um evento de click ao clickar em uma linha de uma DataTable no Vuetify, eu tentei de vários jeitos mais não consegui ainda. O evento de click não foi ao menos reconhecido ainda.

**DataTable:**

```
  <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="cabecalho"
      :items="items"
      :search="search"
      click:row
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <tr @click:row="redirecionar(props.item.idproblema)">
          <td>{{ props.item.idproblema }}</td>
          <td >{{ props.item.titulo }}</td>
          <td >{{ props.item.estado }}</td>
          <td >{{ props.item.gravidade }}</td>
          <td >{{ props.item.prioridade}}</td>
          <td >{{ props.item.atualizacao }}</td>
          </tr>
        </template>
        </v-data-table>
```

**Função:**

```
redirecionar: function(id){
              localStorage.setItem('pro', id);//seta uma variável na cache do navegador do usuário a partir de uma chave
              this.$router.push('/problema');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi remover o s de items e deixar item no slot.

```
<template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
```